# Webscraping image based website - Python, Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Newb here. I want to scrape text from websites that use images with text embedded in them. Example:
https://www.fiio.com/fh9

I don't know any tools or frameworks. Your help is greatly appreciated because I have tens of product descriptions like those to scrape and doing it manually would take me ages. I'd rather learn how to code ;)

I tried:

I'm going through tutorials on Selenium but I still don't know if that's the right tool. I have used Inspect function in Chrome and it detects giant block and nothing else. I can't even separate between menu buttons and the main part of the description.

Before that, tried using Chat GPT-4 in Bing to scrape text but he omitted many parts. Also, if text was on an animted part (slider with two pictures), it wouldn't get it.

Comment: Some of the application was blended with Unity and graphics, which you cannot automate. that is the limitation of automation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.